# Which is the Spring JAR for http://www.springframework.org/schema/util

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724773/autowiring-a-bean-with-list-of-values-in-a-property), but for this I need to have the Spring JAR which has http://www.springframework.org/schema/util namespace.

I searched a lot but couldn't find the name of the JAR which has this namespace, I even downloaded a lot of Spring support JAR and checked the .schemas file but no good. Can someone please let me know the JAR name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically from your question, you are trying to use util namespace.To use the tags in the util schema, you need to have the following preamble at the top of your Spring XML configuration file, so that the tags in the util namespace are available to you.

The jar name is spring-beans-xxx.RELEASE.jar.

You need to mention it in your xml file something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
</beans>
```

Please refer [Spring-docs-XML-util](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util)

Answer (score 2):

It's a namespace :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

</beans>
```

More info here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util

Answer (score 1):

`spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar` ?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/resources/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd